# How to unit test methods that interact with System (or Android) classes

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

How do you manage to write unit tests that interact with the system classes i.e. Android Framework classes?

Imagine you have those classes:

```
public class DeviceInfo {
    public final int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    public final String model;

    public DeviceInfo(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, String deviceModel) {
        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
        this.model = deviceModel;
    }

}

public class DeviceInfoProvider {
    private final Context context;

    public DeviceInfoProvider(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DeviceInfo getScreenParams() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        String model= Build.MODEL;
        DeviceInfo params = new DeviceInfo(screenWidth, screenHeight, model);
        return params;
    }
}
```

How can I write a test to verify the correct behaviour of the method `DeviceInfoProvider.getScreenParams()`.

The following test passes, but it is very ugly and fragile:

```
@Test
public void testGetScreenParams() throws Exception {
    // Setup
    Context context = spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    DeviceInfoProvider deviceInfoProvider = new DeviceInfoProvider(context);

    // Stub
    WindowManager mockWindowManager = mock(WindowManager.class);
    Display mockDisplay = mock(Display.class);
    when(context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockWindowManager);
    when(mockWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay()).thenReturn(mockDisplay);
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = (DisplayMetrics) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            metrics.scaledDensity = 3.25f;
            metrics.widthPixels = 1081;
            metrics.heightPixels = 1921;
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockDisplay).getMetrics(any(DisplayMetrics.class));

    // Run
    DeviceInfo deviceInfo = deviceInfoProvider.getScreenParams();

    // Verify
    assertThat(deviceInfo.screenWidth, equalTo(1081));
    assertThat(deviceInfo.screenHeight, equalTo(1921));
    assertThat(deviceInfo.model, equalTo(Build.MODEL));
}
```

How would you improve that?

Note: Currently I'm using Robolectric, Mockito and PowerMock

Comment: abstract the context specific code so that it can be mocked for unit test. try to avoid mocking classes you don't own.

Comment: is `DeviceInfoProvider` meant to be used as a dependency?

Comment: the question is: Why do you want to test this? Don't you trust the Google guys? You should unit test *your* code in the first place and mock out dependencies you are not responsible for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The System Under Test is too tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Try to avoid mocking classes you don't own. Abstract code behind interfaces and delegate responsibility to whichever implementation happens to be behind the interface at run time.

```
public interface DisplayProvider {
    public int widthPixels;
    public int heightPixels;
}

public interface BuildProvider {
    public string Model;
}
```

Refactor dependent class to rely on the abstractions and not concretions (implementation concerns).

```
public class DeviceInfoProvider {
    private final DisplayProvider display;
    private final BuildProvider build;

    public DeviceInfoProvider(DisplayProvider display, BuildProvider build) {
        this.display = display;
        this.build = build;
    }

    public DeviceInfo getScreenParams() {
        int screenWidth = display.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = display.heightPixels;
        String model = build.Model;
        DeviceInfo params = new DeviceInfo(screenWidth, screenHeight, model);
        return params;
    }
}
```

Unit test in isolation

```
@Test
public void testGetScreenParams() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    DisplayProvider mockDisplay = mock(DisplayProvider.class);
    BuildProvider mockBuild = mock(BuildProvider.class);        
    DeviceInfoProvider deviceInfoProvider = new DeviceInfoProvider(mockDisplay, mockBuild);

    when(mockDisplay.widthPixels).thenReturn(1081);
    when(mockDisplay.heightPixels).thenReturn(1921);
    when(mockBuild.Model).thenReturn(Build.MODEL);

    // Act
    DeviceInfo deviceInfo = deviceInfoProvider.getScreenParams();

    // Assert
    assertThat(deviceInfo.screenWidth, equalTo(1081));
    assertThat(deviceInfo.screenHeight, equalTo(1921));
    assertThat(deviceInfo.model, equalTo(Build.MODEL));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a nice advice. But, if you want to test the new DisplayProvider and BuildProvider, you'll need to mock the system classes at the end, right?

Comment: Again those classes will be wrapping implementation concerns that would have already been extensible tested by their providers. This will also be leaving unit testing domain and crossing into integration testing.

Comment: What about mocking **Context**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you do not mock Context. It is an implementation concern that only the derived implementations should be concerned about. The whole reason for abstracting that dependency it so that you don't have to mock that, but rather abstract around it.